# capnp - how to write plain serialized message to a file

Tags: c++, capnproto

I have build the example of the AddressBook from [Example Usage](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html#example-usage). It worked as expected I serialized it in the packed format  `writePackedMessageToFd(fd, message)`, but when I tried to serialize it in the 'plain' format 
`writeMessageToFd(fd, message)`

it kept producing empty file... I feel that I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a confusion, the file was written only i couldn't see it in eclipse internal reader.